# Adding options to loop

Tags: loop, dashboard

I made my first theme for Wordpress, but I am interested in one thing so if anyone can point me to right direction.

My theme has 4-5 loops, depending on category that it need to show. I want to add choice in admin panel or dashboard where person can chose which category each loop will show. Option would be just like text container, person enters a cat id and save it and that variable in called than in the loop.

Thanks for reading, would be nice if anyone could point me to some materials, cheers :-).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`add_meta_boxes`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/add_meta_boxes) hook to place a text field in the desired pages. Then on the template page you can check whether the user has entered some categories (display all categories if not) and filter the loop using the [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), [`query_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) or [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts). [Here is an excellent article on the three methods](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

Comment: Hmm, thanks fo info. I will try to download some free theme that supports same and check how they done.